# Why primary key error is showing even if i have relevant decorator in my entity using typeorm?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, typeorm

I am using `typeorm` and `postgres`. I have an entity called `product` which looks like this

```
 import { BaseEntity, Column, CreateDateColumn, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";

 @Entity('product')

 export class Product extends BaseEntity {

   @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
   @Column()
   id: number;

   @Column({
      unique: true,
      length: 200,
      nullable: false
   })
   name: string;

   @Column()
      description: string;

   @Column({
      nullable: false
   })
   cost: number;

   @Column({
      nullable: false
   })
   price: number;

   @Column()
      weight: string;

   @CreateDateColumn()
   created_at: Date

 }
```

I have my `DataSource` like this

```
export const dataSourceConnectionInstance = () =>  {
return new DataSource({
    type: 'postgres',
    host: process.env.PG_HOST,
    port: Number(process.env.PG_PORT),
    username: process.env.PG_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.PG_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.PG_DATABASE,
    entities: [Product, Orders, Users],
    synchronize: true
 })
}
```

It can be seen that i have placed `PrimaryGeneratedColumn` decorator for `id` field. But still i am getting this error

```
MissingPrimaryColumnError: Entity "Product" does not have a primary column. Primary column is required to have in all your entities. Use @PrimaryColumn decorator to add a primary column to your entity.
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution. The mistake was, i was adding both decorators i.e `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn`, `@Column` to the field `id` which was wrong. It should be like this

```
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: number;
```

instead of this

```
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
@Column()
id: number;
```